# Color PS1 based on previous command output

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, bashrc

I have my current PS1 as follows. The `$?` output is really useful (second line).

```
export PS1="\
${PSOn_Blue}${PSBWhite}\t\
${PSColor_Off} \$?\
${PSColor_Off}${PSBGreen} \u\
${PSColor_Off}${PSWhite}@\
${PSColor_Off}${hostcolor}\h\
${PSColor_Off}:\
${PSBGreen}\w\
${PSColor_Off}\$\
 "
```

It would be even nicer if the return code ($?) would be red on non-zero output.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [this](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/9a3d2ea4762194b3c6956651b20fd3fa696ee257/.bashrc#L57-L64):

```
BOLD_FORMAT="${BOLD_FORMAT-$(color_enabled && tput bold)}"
ERROR_FORMAT="${ERROR_FORMAT-$(color_enabled && tput setaf 1)}"
RESET_FORMAT="${RESET_FORMAT-$(color_enabled && tput sgr0)}"

PS1='$(exit_code=$?; [ $exit_code -eq 0 ] || printf %s $BOLD_FORMAT $ERROR_FORMAT $exit_code $RESET_FORMAT " ")'
```

Concatenate that with the rest of your `$PS1`, but make sure you still use the single quotes, otherwise it won't work, and you should be golden. If you want to display the exit code even if it's zero, simply remove the `[ $exit_code -eq 0 ] ||` bit.

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful. Will look into tput things, haven't seen those before.

Comment: `tput` ensures that it won't produce ugly escape codes if your terminal doesn't support color.

Comment: I see. I just miss escaping of the nonprintable characters... Do you have that working?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This would show the basename of the working directory (`\W`) in green or red:

```
PS1='\[\e[$([[ $? = 0 ]] && printf 32 || printf 31);1m\]\W\[\e[m\] '
```